# Grouping and Transposing pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a dataframe, with a list of health record data retrieved in a dict:

```json
{'identifier': '1519288', 'name': 'Blood Pressure', 'code': '55284-4', 'date': datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 24, 18, 17, 40, tzinfo=<FixedOffset '-05:00'>), 'value': [71.6, 145.3], 'subject_id': 'Patient/1519283', 'resource_type': 'Observation'}
{'identifier': '1519289', 'name': 'Total Cholesterol', 'code': '2093-3', 'date': datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 10, 18, 17, 40, tzinfo=<FixedOffset '-05:00'>), 'value': 300.2, 'subject_id': 'Patient/1519283', 'resource_type': 'Observation'}
{'identifier': '1519290', 'name': 'Total Cholesterol', 'code': '2093-3', 'date': datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 10, 18, 17, 40, tzinfo=<FixedOffset '-05:00'>), 'value': 299, 'subject_id': 'Patient/1519283', 'resource_type': 'Observation'}
```

The dataframe `pd.DataFrame(dict)` looks like the following:

[image]

How can I group and pivot such that it looks like this:

| Total Cholesterol | High Density Lipoprotein Cholesterol | Triglycerides |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 300.2 | 22.3 | 200 |
| 200 | - | - |
| 300.2 | - | - |

**The reason for doing this is to plot these tests. I'm not sure if this is the right way to do that?**

I could get the values in the form of a list using this: `records_df[['name', 'value']].groupby('name')['value'].apply(list)` but I'm not sure how to plot it.

output:

```
name
Blood Pressure                              [[71.6, 145.3]]
High Density Lipoprotein Cholesterol                 [22.3]
Low Density Lipoprotein Cholesterol              [155, 134]
Tobacco smoking status NHIS                          [None]
Total Cholesterol                       [300.2, 299, 300.2]
Triglycerides                                         [200]
atorvastatin 20 MG tablet                               [1]
Name: value, dtype: object
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. And don't provide input as an image, make it text or code

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pivot` to reshape your dataframe. However, I think you need to preprocess your `'Blood Pressure'` rows and convert them to `['Diastolic Blood Pressure', 'Systolic Blood Pressure']`.

```
# 'Blood Pressure' -> ['Diastolic Blood Pressure', 'Systolic Blood Pressure']
names = df['name'].mask(df['name'].eq('Blood Pressure'), 
                        other=pd.Series([['Diastolic Blood Pressure',
                                          'Systolic Blood Pressure']]))

cols = ['name', 'value']
out = (df[cols].assign(name=names).explode(cols)
                .assign(row=lambda x: x.groupby('name').cumcount())
                .pivot(index='row', columns='name', values='value')
                .rename_axis(index=None, columns=None))
```

Output:

```
>>> out
  Diastolic Blood Pressure Systolic Blood Pressure Total Cholesterol
0                     71.6                   145.3             300.2
1                      NaN                     NaN               299
```